# Cannot assign client certificate to SSIS Http connection Manager

Tags: web-services, ssis, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to consume a web service using a web service task in SSIS. The connection is https and I have a certificate in the trust store to enable the connection. I am trying to add the certificate to an Http connection manager, but every time I click the certificate button, I get a dialog box which says 'No certificates meet the application criteria'. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to do SSIS Code Signing for your certificate.

This can be done by either:

1. From Business Intelligence Development Studio, using Digital Signing option in the SSIS tab.
2. Using DTUtil command line utility combined with the /SIGN switch.

Follow the article for step step guide. 
[Digital Signing a SSIS package](http://munishbansal.wordpress.com/2009/05/15/digital-signing-a-ssis-package-sql-server-2005-integration-services-security/)